# Concepto de paso por referencia y valor

Tags: java, c

sé que el el tema ya ha sido comentado y he ido checando detalladamente las aportaciones que se han presentado durante cada uno ,gracias a ellos creo que he logrado capturar realmente el concepto pero aún me quedan dudas de si lo he hecho de la manera correcta, les agradecería si alguien me pudiera confirmar mis hipótesis planteadas a continuación.

**Puntos a considerar.**

1.Java no cuenta con pasos por referencia.

2.C y C++ cuentan con pasos por refrencia.

Todos los lenguajes anteriores los he cubierto hasta los temas necesario para poder realizar este tipo de comparaciones.En Java puedo expresar la siguiente linea.

```
Persona p1 = new Persona();
```

Mientras que en C puedo realizar lo siguiente con estructuras.

```
Persona p1;
Persona *ptrPersona = &p1;
```

A partir de los ejemplos anteriores yo pensaba lo siguiente.

**Java.**

1.La referencia p1 hace referencia al objeto creado en esa misma linea de manera que la variable p1 contiene la dirección de memoria de dicho objeto.

**C.**

2.El puntero ptrPersona apunta hacia al objeto p1.

Es aquí donde tenia un choque de conceptos...Yo pensaba que el hecho de que el puntero en C apuntara hacia un objeto hacia énfasis en que el puntero era simplemente un tipo de variable que contenía direcciones de memoria pero al pensar en eso chocaba con el concepto de referencias en java y me surgía la duda 
de cual era la diferencia entre la referencia en java y el puntero en C si en ambos cuando se pasaban a una función realmente lo que se hacia era copiar esa dirección de memoria al parámetro de la función.

A partir de lo anterior intente buscar una respuesta que realmente me diera solucion a esta incognita y que me termino confundiendo un poco.

**Puntos Hipotéticos que ahora creo entender.**

1.El apuntador en C realmente no es una variable que contiene direcciones de memoria ,simplemente es un alias para la dirección de memoria a la que apunta.

2.La referencia en Java si guardar una dirección de memoria.

A través de los puntos anteriores entonces intente enlazar todas las respuestas que encontre... y llegue a la suposición de que el paso por referencia no existe en java y si en C por las siguientes circunstancias.

1.En C existe un paso por referencia debido a que si tu pasas un apuntador a una función realmente no le estas diciendo al parámetro de la función que copie la dirección de memoria que contiene el primer apuntador si no que le estas diciendo que ahora la variable parámetro va ser un nuevo alias para la dirección de memoria que "apuntaba" el primer apuntador o mas bien dicho a la que era alias el primer apuntador.

2.En Java no existe un paso por referencia debido a que si tu pasas una referencia de un objeto realmente lo único que estas pasando es la dirección de memoria,esto implica que indirectamente el lenguaje java deberá realizar un proceso oculto para acceder a esa dirección de memoria y que ademas en las celdas de memoria se tendrá almacenadas dos referencias o variables distintas que contienen una dirección de memoria igual de un objeto.

Les agradecería si me confirmaran si realmente esta es la diferencia que limita a que lenguajes como java no soporten  el paso de parámetros por referencia a una función, ademas me gustaría recalcar el punto del puntero en C...Realmente un puntero en C no es como una variable que puede contener un valor(dirección de memoria) si no que es algo mas avanzado de manera que no contiene nada pero permite ser un alias para una dirección de memoria.Lo anterior lo menciono por que realmente he visto algunos autores menciona un puntero en C como una variable especial que contiene direcciones de memoria.

Comment: Te estás complicando mucho mucho; demasiado. En Java no hay punteros porque ... el lenguaje se diseño así, al igual que tantos otros como Python, Javascript, lua, haskell, ... En todos estos, salvo documentación oficial en contra, el como funcionan es un *detalle de implementación*, y realmente **no nos hace falta saberlo**. No tiene sentido comparar conceptos en lenguajes distintos, cuando dichos conceptos **no están presentes** en dichos lenguajes.

Comment: Hasta donde yo se un puntero es una variable. Como tal almacena una dirección de memoria. Como es un puntero, el contenido de esa dirección, es otra dirección de memoria, donde se encuentra el inicio del dato apuntado. Una variable que no es un puntero, directamente tiene la posición de memoria donde esta el dato.

Comment: @Trauma en java no existe la aritmetica de punteros, pero cada vez que haces un new (cualquier cosa) estas haciendo uso de punteros.

Comment: Estas confundiendo muchos conceptos. TODO se guarda en variables. No importa lo que guardes, todo se guarda ahi. No recuerdo si java maneja el concepto de boxed o no, pero eso implicaria si la variable tiene directamente el dato, o es un puntero al dato. Ahora, lenguajes de mas alto nivel como java o C# encapsulan el concepto de punteros. Sin embargo, en varios lenguajes si podes pasar cosas por referencia o por valor, solo que no todas, porque asi fue diseñado el lenguaje.

Answer (score 2):

En C un puntero guarda la dirección de memoria de otra variable. Por ejemplo:

```
int someNumber = 0;
int *pointer = &someNumber;

printf("Entero guardado en la variable: %x\n", someNumber);
printf("Dirección de memoria donde está someNumber: %x\n", &someNumber);
printf("Dirección de memoria donde está someNumber: %x\n", pointer);
printf("Acceso a el valor de la variable desde el puntero: %x\n", *pointer);
//Salida
Entero guardado en la variable: 0
Dirección de memoria donde está someNumber: e6e8edb4
Dirección de memoria donde está someNumber: e6e8edb4
Acceso a el valor de la variable desde el puntero: 0
```

Puedes verlo en acción y modificarlo a tu gusto aquí: http://tpcg.io/2Vy5RC

En Java hay punteros igual pero no se usan explícitamente el lenguaje los abstrae para que no tengas que preocuparte por ellos. Así que cuando haces:

```
Persona p1 = new Persona();
```

Efectivamente p1 es una referencia a la memoria donde está guardado tu objeto. Pero cuando Java usa **el paso por valor** cuando llama a un método, de tal manera que tú dentro de ese método trabajas con una copia de tu objeto. Mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```
public void swapAttempt(Point point1, Point point2)
{
  point.x = 100;
  point.y = 100;
  Point temp = point1;
  point1 = point2;
  point2 = temp;
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
  Point point1 = new Point(0,0);
  Point point2 = new Point(0,0);

  System.out.println("X: " + point1.x + " Y: " + point1.y); 
  System.out.println("X: " + point2.x + " Y: " + point2.y);

  swapAttempt(point1, point2);

  System.out.println("X: " + point1.x + " Y: " + point1.y); 
  System.out.println("X: " + point2.x + " Y: " + point2.y);  
}
```

La salida es la siguiente:

```
X: 0 Y: 0
X: 0 Y: 0
X: 100 Y: 100
X: 0 Y: 0
```

Como puedes ver, el objeto original no se ha modificado aunque en el método si que se modifique. Si quisieras guardar el objeto modificado tendrías que devolverlo en el método y asignárselo de nuevo a la variable `p1` original.

Puedes jugar con el ejemplo aquí: http://tpcg.io/x9hRc5